# Copy from one workbook to another including tables

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another. The sheet where the data is at is in Table form but when i try the below code it does not work. Before the copy happens, it first does a filter and then copies the data.

```
Sub Details()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\mi\Extracts.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\mi\Outstanding.xlsm")


    x.Sheets.ListObjects("FIdetails").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

    x.Sheets.ListObjects("FIdetails").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Magnesium"

        lastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("b4").End(xlToRight).Column
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("b4", ActiveSheet.Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Copy

'paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Details").Range("A2").Paste


End Sub
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note following points regarding your code

- a) `x.Sheets.ListObjects` does not identify variables and their
  association correctly and would give compiler error whereas
  `x.ActiveSheet.ListObjects` is correct.
- b)  Repetition of Filter line    twice is not understandable.
- c)   You have to use visibleCells    property for copying filtered
  cells in your method.
- d)   You have to    either Activate the sheet to be worked upon or
  use With ... End with    structure. Later one is a preferable
  approach.
- e)    To clear filter    use `ShowAlldata` property.

I recorded a macro to demonstrate its potential.

```
  Sub Macro()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    Cells.Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="FIdetails"
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FIdetails").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "magnesium"
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Outstanding.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Extracts.xlsm").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Subsequently if you run the program it generates error particularly on line `Application.Goto Reference:="FIdetails"` and also is not reliable in performance. Further it uses 'Select' which preferably be avoided keeping in view following highly acclaimed SO Posts.

[What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

[Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Finally I chose array based approach, which I think may give better & consistent results.

Try This:

```
    Sub Details()
    Dim Results As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim CriteriaCol As Long, ResultCount As Long
    Dim Criteria As String

    Criteria = "Magnesium"
    CriteriaCol = 1

    With Sheet1.ListObjects("FIdetails")
        tmp = .DataBodyRange
    End With

    ReDim Results(LBound(tmp, 2) To UBound(tmp, 2), LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1))
    For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
        If UCase(tmp(i, CriteriaCol)) = UCase(Criteria) Then
            ResultCount = ResultCount + 1
            j = LBound(tmp, 2) - 1
            Do
                j = j + 1
                Results(j, ResultCount) = tmp(i, j)
            Loop Until j = UBound(tmp, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Results(LBound(Results, 1) To UBound(Results, 1), LBound(Results, 1) To ResultCount)
    With Workbooks("Outstanding.xlsm").Sheets("Details")
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(Results, 2), UBound(Results, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Results)
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Screenshots of sample data and results added for OP's guidance based on his comments dated 07-03-2019. 
[image: filter1]
[image: filter2]

Comment: Thank you this seems to work great. I have not done this type of VBA yet so thanks. But the only thing is, i only want it to copy from the second column and 4th row. (B4). There is stuff in Column A and lines 1,2 and 3.

Comment: @Lalaland Is your data in a defined table or a simple range. not in table. Further can you upload a sample file with factitious data so that I may  test and modify my code to suit your requirements  fully.

Comment: Hi there, i have uploaded the file i use to copy from, so everything in yellow needs to be copied and pasted to other sheet.

Comment: So basically after doing the filter for Magnesium, then the copy will take place but i dont want to copy the actual colum "magnisum". I have highlighted the columns in yellow which should help.

Comment: @Lalaland I wanted to make minimum changes to the program routine as it is of universal application and want not to disturb looping portion. I have made minor changes at two places to accomplish your purpose.I have uploaded a word document highlighting changed portion with yellow shade. I hope it should do your  job. In case you are satisfied by my efforts for you please accept my answer. Copy from one workbook to another including tables<https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vqh2anayy5hgyg/55018080-Copy%20from%20one%20workbook%20to%20another.docx?dl=0>

Comment: That is working perfect, thank you so much for all your effort it is really appreciated.

Comment: @Lalaland  please remove your File upload  link from Question as it contains your specific information.